# How well different featuremap encode the data？

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

Recently, I was doing research on QML. Qiskit gave detailed steps on how to encode data into quantum states, but I was confused about one point: there are different feature mapping methods under qiskit.circuit.library, such as : ZZFeatureMap, PauliFeatureMap, etc. I would like to ask if they have different applicability to different structured data?
Are they a general way of feature mapping?
For the study of regression datasets, which one is the best featuremap method?

Comment: A ZZFeature Map(PauliFeatureMap with entanglement) provides a genuine quantum advantage while a ZFeatureMap(PauliFeatureMap without entanglement) does not as such provide any known quantum advantage due to absence of the entanglement operator. You can also create custom feature maps using Qiskit's NLocal and TwoLocal library.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, I just took a look at these two classes, but I have some doubts about the ’linear‘ entanglement in them. What are the effects of linear and nonlinear entanglement on featuremap & data encoding?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to ask if they have different applicability to different structured data?

In a way, yes. In one of the original papers which introduced quantum kernel methods ([Havlicek, 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11326)), the ZZFeatureMap was used in an experimental demonstration as an example of a quantum kernel method that could succeed at classification on a dataset that was *conjectured*$^1$ to be computationally inefficient (exponential time) to classify with a classical learning algorithm (provided that the feature map has 2 or more layers). The dataset that they performed the experiment on was contrived - i.e., they created a dataset that this specific kernel would succeed on while most others would fail.

Some interesting recent works (e.g. [Glick, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.03406), [Meyer, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.06217)) demonstrate how a given feature map might take advantages of symmetries in classical data, but otherwise there are few concrete cases where quantum kernel methods have been shown to offer a rigorous speedup over classical methods. One example is in ([Liu, 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02174)), which showed a speedup if the classical data are labeled according to some discrete log function.

> Are they a general way of feature mapping?

No, they are rather specific. A more general way of constructing a feature map is choosing *any* $U(x)$ that depends on your input data $x$ in some way, and then estimating the quantum kernel as
$$
k(x, x') = |\langle 0| U^\dagger (x') U(x)|0\rangle|^2
$$
by sampling the output distribution of a quantum circuit. The feature maps provided by qiskit are specific choices of $U$ that have appeared in literature or are otherwise just plausible (but not strongly motivated) choices. But there are still other ways of preparing feature maps. Off the top of my head, ([Liu, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.12004)) prepares feature maps by continuous time evolution (instead of a discrete-time circuit model) while ([Heyraud, 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.12192)) defines feature maps with respect to a set of observables in a quantum system. New proposals come out all the time.

> For the study of regression datasets, which one is the best feature map method?

This is unknown, even in classical machine learning! For example, a Gaussian kernel or a polynomial kernel (both classically efficient to compute) may each perform better or worse at generalizing on a dataset depending on how that dataset is structured. There is no "best" feature map because there is no free lunch in machine learning - a certain kernel will always perform poorly for *some* choice of dataset.

---

$^1$ There are many caveats here: They used 2 qubits in the experimental demonstration, but of course this is efficient to simulate classically and so a demonstration of actual quantum advantage would require many more qubits. Furthermore, at the time the authors provided some arguments that it would be classically hard to sample from the output of the ZZFeatureMap (basically a series of concatenated IQP circuits) but I recall the arguments fell short of rigorous. I don't know the current status of this conjectured hardness argument.

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help. If it answers your question feel free to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article can help you: 'Automatic design of quantum feature maps', Sergio Altares-López, Angela Ribeiro and Juan José García-Ripoll, 19 August 2021 - https://doi.org/10.1088/2058-9565/ac1ab1.

They describe a technique to generate optimal quantum feature maps for classification tasks by using multiobjetive genetic algorithm.